# xelatex stop running with no error raised

Tags: xetex, latex3

I run my tex file on CentOS7 using xelatex. I can see its progress in `top` but seems it stopped runnning with no error raised. And the final sentence on screen is:

`(/project/RD/transcriptome/software/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd)`

Then it stopped here, no more running record on screen.
And if I press `Ctrl+C` to stop, it shows like this:

```
! Interruption. 
__kernel_file_name_expand_loop:w ..._group:nTF {#1
                                                  }{__kernel_file_name_expan...
l.78 \end{titlepage}

?
```

tex scripts near line 78 is like this:

```
\begin{document}
% 封面设置
\begin{titlepage}
    % 封面图
    \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.2}{titlepages.png}

    \heiti
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{90pt}
        \zihao{2} \textbf{Company Name}\\
        \vspace*{20pt}
        \zihao{2} \textbf{Report Name}\\
        \vspace*{200pt}
    \end{center}

    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{lcc}
            \zihao{-3} Series Number：& 00000000 \\
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Project Type：& 转录组 \\ 
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Customer Name：& XXX \\ 
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Customer Company：& XXXX \\
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Sample Number：& 40 \\ 
            \specialrule{0em}{5pt}{5pt}
            \zihao{-3} Report Date：& \today \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{titlepage} % Here is line 78.
```

And I don't know why it stopped but no error raised, and did it really stop? I can still see its progress in `top` and its status is 'R'.

if any error is found, please tell me! Thanks!! :)

Here updated a sample for test:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[UTF8]{article}

\usepackage{ctex} % 编译中文
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry} % 这个包用来调整纸张大小和页边距
\geometry{left=2.0cm,top=2.0cm,right=2.0cm,bottom=2.0cm}
\usepackage{setspace} % 设置行距
\setlength{\parindent}{2em} % 设置首行缩进

% 字体相关
\usepackage{fontspec} % 用于设置英文字体
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\usepackage{xeCJK} % 用于设置中文字体
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun-Regular}
\setCJKsansfont{Heiti-Light}

% 图表相关
\usepackage{graphicx} % 插入图片
\usepackage{caption} % 插入图片标题
\usepackage{wallpaper} % 添加背景图
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{colortbl}

% 页眉页脚
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
% \fancyhead{} % 初始化页眉
\rhead{\bfseries Right head od this page}
\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{any\_picture.png}}
% \fancyfoot{} % 初始化页脚
\cfoot{page foot text here}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{document}
% 封面设置
\begin{titlepage}
    % 封面图
    \ThisCenterWallPaper{1.2}{any\_cover\_pic.png}
    \begin{center}
        \vspace*{90pt}
        \zihao{2} \textbf{Title}\\
        \vspace*{20pt}
        \zihao{2} \textbf{subtitle}\\
        \vspace*{200pt}
    \end{center}

\end{titlepage}

\section{Part1 -A sample}
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
Here is the test text.Just for test.
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it looks as if you produced a loop, but you will have to show a small but complete example so that one can test it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Actually I haven't mean to make a loop and also cannot find any loop in my tex file. I have updated a sample to this question. Thanks!

Comment: After fighting a bit with the fonts, I get no loop. Are you sure you want to load both `ctex` and `xeCJK`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, cause I have to write Chinese in my tex file. Seems `ctex` and `xeCJK` are both needed?

Comment: 1. If you need to output Chinese, you only need the ctex package. 2. Your supplementary example does not reproduce your question.